# Transfer entity knowledge between apps

Tags: wit.ai

What is the easiest way to transfer one entity knowledge (including all expressions that is labeled by the entity) from one private apps to another private apps (same developer)?

My current method are:

1. Export both projects to two zip files.
2. Copy the needed entity.json in folder entities and expressions.json from first app zip file to the second app zip file.
3. Create third app by importing the updated zip.

Is there a better way?